# storing a string with separated space into one index bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, for-loop

Here is my code

```
# text file has: column1:column2:column3:column4:column5:column6:column7
# such as: tang:orange juice

while read line ; do
fields=($(printf "%s" "$line" | cut -d':' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1-))
     for i in "${fields[@]}" ; do
            echo $i  #i also tried echo "$i" but same result
     done
done < file.txt
```

my output would be like:

```
tang
orange
juice
```

but it should be like:

```
tang
orange juice
```

Comment: Lynchburg, please try to avoid posting things as links (especially graphical links) when they can be better put into the question itself and text.

Comment: sorry, my bad..

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFS` to specify the field separator for the shell. Then you can split the line using `:` as the separator.

```
IFS=: fields=($line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you turn the colons into spaces to handle the things as words, not taking into account the fact that some things *already* have spaces. That means they'll be split into separate words as well.

If your intent is just to take each line of input and place each thing on its own line, you can use something like `sed 's/:/\n/g'` as in the following transcript:

```
pax:~> printf "tang:orange juice:coke\nwater:pale ale\n" | sed 's/:/\n/g'
tang
orange juice
coke
water
pale ale
```

In your particular case, that would be the relatively simple:

```
sed 's/:/\n/g' file.txt
```

Comment: my goal here is that for every line delimited by : it would be stored into an array which I would use later on for test commands before I put it into my SQL table

Answer (score 0):

Besides the very short version from @Barmar this would do it in a slightly longer way, which might be more intuitive for a beginner.

```
while IFS=: read -r -a fields
do
    printf "%s\n" "${fields[@]}"
done < file.txt
```